# How do I use nVidia GPU on 16.04 Xenial?

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, intel-graphics

I've a Haswell 4670 CPU with Intel Graphics that I've been used for a couple of years.

Recently acquired and physically installed an nVidia GTX 1610 card. But when I plug my monitor onto the card's DVI slot and turn on my system I can't see nothing.

If I login via a VNC application I can see in: System Settings > Details > Overview" That Ubuntu is still using "Intel Haswell Desktop" graphics instead of the nVidia.

So far I've added the `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` PPA and can see on the list at "Software & Updates > Additional Drivers" NVIDIA 367, NVIDIA 370 and X.org Nouveau alongside with the Intel driver.

I can pick from the list any option, but after clicking "Apply" button my choice get unchecked, the check mark goes back to X.org entry and it asks me to restart.

After restarting everything is the same, I can plug my monitor on the MoBo's DVI port and use my system without problem, but if I plug it into the nVidia port the monitor only shows a "No signal message".

If relevant, MoBo is Gigabyte GA-Z87-HD3.

Any hints?

Comment: I'm going to +1 this question...
I have installed the `ppa` repository as well... i cant even get a list of drivers to show up... `Ubuntu Studio 16.041`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into the BIOS and set the Initial Display output to the slot your new card is in. I have had several Gigabyte boards over the years and they all default to onboard graphics unless you make this adjustment. See [this page](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/689955/Gigabyte-Ga-Z87x-Hd3.html?page=50&term=PCIE&selected=13) of your motherboard manual for more detail.

Comment: Thank you, that really helped. Now I got image, sadly once the system boots I got a dialog stating that it is running on low graphics mode and asking me to configure it. Have clicked all options, but won't let me go further. I can however drop to the command line and log into my user to install software. Have any idea on how to proceed with the driver installation?

Comment: That's a different question. Fortunately the answer is here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers